# MP3 file is not playing in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to play audio file in iPhone,but it is not playing properly and throw error 
"The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -43.) in iphone" and app crash. But this mp3 file is playing in Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File name's in simulator is case insensitive whereas file names on device is case sensitive. Check your mp3 file name is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below on your Mac OS terminal,you will get the reason for the error.

```
$ macerror -43
```

Response

```
Mac OS error -43 (fnfErr): File not found
```

Check the file at your given path ....

Here is the good tutorial to know more abt the `OSErr` & `OSStatus` errors.

http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/carbon-for-the-cocoa-guy-oserror-and-osstatus/

Answer (score 0):

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID doesn't work with MP3 files on the device. If you use that method, try converting it to WAV and let me know if it worked! If not, explain a bit what code you use to play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

When a file works in the simulator and not the device it could be the string case of your file name. iphone devices is case sensitive for file names.